# Shopware 5 exporting orders with free text field (attr1) impossible?

Tags: shopware, shopware5

I am trying to export orders and we need the csv to include a free text field (attribute 1) we set in the articles. But I read that these free text fields aren't possible to export in profile orders.
Isn't there any way to do that?

Comment: Adding the product free text fields in the order profile is currently not possible out of the box. If you like, you can create a ticket for that: https://issues.shopware.com/createissue

Answer (score 0):

A more inconvenient and workintesive way, would be to gather all the data from the database and then export it to a .csv file. I don't know if this may help you, since I don't know for what you need the export and how fit you are with queries and database in general.